# Android WebView not showing a JavaScript section of website

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

Thanks for reading!

I am using a WebView to show a mobile website. There is a `page.html` which does the `AJAX xmlHttpRequest.responseText` to fetch the page content.

I see the entire website except two sections displaying ads.

```
<div class="top-banner" class="top-rule">
<div id="hp_leaderboard" class="adContainer">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var agent=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var is_iphone = ((agent.indexOf('iphone')!=-1));
if(is_iphone)
{
OAS_AD('MISC1'); } else {
OAS_AD('TOP');
}
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

I have done

```
WebSettings = this.page.getSettings(); //page is a WebView
s.setJavaScriptEnabled(); //enable JavaScript
```

I am fairly new to HTML/JS. Could someone please help?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Adding code. Note: The section below and the the `<div>` section above appears in the `<body>` tag

```
<script language="JavaScript"><!--
//configuration
OAS_sitepage = 'www.boston.com/mobile/homepage';
var agent=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();var is_iphone = ((agent.indexOf('iphone')!=-1));if(is_iphone) {
OAS_listpos = 'MISC1,FOOTER,INTRO';
}else{
OAS_listpos = 'TOP,FOOTER,INTRO';
}
OAS_query='Unknown+Terminal';
OAS_url='http://rmedia.boston.com/RealMedia/ads/';OAS_target='_top';OAS_version=10;OAS_rn='001234567890';OAS_rns='1234567890';OAS_rn=new String(Math.random());OAS_rns=OAS_rn.substring(2, 11);
function OAS_NORMAL(pos){document.writeln('<A HREF="'+OAS_url+'click_nx.ads/'+OAS_sitepage+'/1'+OAS_rns+'@'+OAS_listpos+'!'+ pos+'?'+OAS_query+'" TARGET='+OAS_target+'>');document.writeln('<IMG SRC="'+OAS_url+'adstream_nx.ads/'+OAS_sitepage+'/1'+OAS_rns+'@'+OAS_listpos+'!'+pos+'?'+OAS_query+'" BORDER=0></A>');}
//--></script><script language="JavaScript1.1"><!--
OAS_version=11;if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mozilla/3')!=-1)||navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mozilla/4.0 WebTV')!=-1){OAS_version=10;}if(OAS_version >= 11)document.writeln('<SCR'+'IPT LANGUAGE=JavaScript1.1 SRC="'+OAS_url+'adstream_mjx.ads/'+OAS_sitepage+'/1'+OAS_rns+'@'+OAS_listpos+'?'+OAS_query+'"> <\/SCRIPT>');
//--></script><script language="JavaScript"><!--
document.writeln('');
function OAS_AD(pos){if(OAS_version >= 11)OAS_RICH(pos);else OAS_NORMAL(pos);}
//-->
</script>
```

**EDIT2:** I also tried `ChromeWebClient` - but turns out it only adds support for JS methods like `alert(), prompt()`,etc. There is not much documentation except [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968936/android-webview-not-loading-a-javascript-file-but-android-browser-loads-it-fine) but the OP seems to have accepted an answer regardless of whether it worked for them. Nevertheless, that solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check these lines of code

```
var agent=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if(is_iphone)
{
  OAS_AD('MISC1'); } else {
  OAS_AD('TOP');
}
```

Obviously in your case the agent is not "iphone" so the code executed is

```
OAS_AD('TOP');
```

It would be useful if you attach that code too...